# Scrape order numbers from Wix.com

Tags: python

I want to organize a PUBG Tournament. To do so, a friend and I have created a website on wix.com. Here interested players can "buy" a ticket for free and get, with this ticket, an order number. Additionally we have set up a Discord Server which is "protected" by a password-bot. The required password should be this order number, which I mentioned earlier.

The "problem" is, that the only way for me, to get these order numbers, is to log in to the wix.com admin site and go to the order overview. There I can either, get an .csv file via pressing a button or scrape the data from the code.

I tried to program the bot to scrape the data, but it just won´t do it.

I really would appreciate any help what so ever. Please be advised, that neither I nor my friend are particularly skilled in Python and we are still learning.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```py
import os
import requests
from lxml import html
import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

EMAIL = "<EMAIL>"
PASSWORD = "<PASSWORD>"

my_secret = os.environ['EMAIL']
my_secret = os.environ['password']

LOGIN_URL = "https://users.wix.com/signin"
URL = "https://manage.wix.com/dashboard/63e1c04d-52a6-49cc-91b2-149afa7ad7a9/events/b1839f48-412d-4274-b4de-2f8417028bcf/guest-list?referralInfo=sidebar"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()



    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "email": EMAIL, 
        "password": PASSWORD, 
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
    Order = tree.xpath("//div[@class='_3Eow9']/a/text()")


    print(Order)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflorw. What is your code doing so far? Along with providing a [MRE], it really helps to describe the current results and how they differ from what you want. (See [ask] as well, there's lots of good guidance there.)

Comment: Also, dumb question but do you ever call `main()`? (And I notice you haven't taken the [tour] yet, that's always a good place to start.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response.
I added main() at the end. Thus far, the code is doing seemingly nothing. Sorry again, we really are newbs :/

Comment: I'm not at a computer to test at the moment, but off the top of my head, you never use the email and password you fetch from environment variables; when you send the request to the server, you give it the placeholders `"<EMAIL>"` and `"<PASSWORD>"`. Liberal use of `print` calls can help debug things like that; check that things actually are what you expect them to be along the way.